# How to return Datetimeoffset in SQL view using at time zone

Tags: sql-server, view, timezone

is it possible to return a value from a table that is of type datetime as datetimeoffset in a view using AT TIME ZONE?

When I try this with

`CREATE VIEW TESTVIEW AS
SELECT        appointment_start AT TIME ZONE 'central european standard time' AS x
FROM            dbo.Appointments`

the result is as expected, but when I open the view in SQL Management Studio, I get the message 'Unable to parse query text.'

The same when I try something like

`SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(appointment_start, DATEPART(tz, appointment_start AT TIME ZONE 'central european standard time')) as y
FROM            dbo.Appointments`

How do I get the datetime value converted to a datetimeoffset using AT TIME ZONE in an SQL view?

EDIT:
When I additionally select another column from the table, I also get the expected result, but the SQL Management Studio complains

SELECT 
id, appointment_start AT TIME ZONE 'central european standard time' AS x
FROM dbo.Appointments

`Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'TIME'.
Missing FROM clause.
Error in list of function arguments: 'AT' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.`

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which version of sql server are you on? `AT TIME ZONE` looks like it's ver 2016+ according to the docs. (Hint: `SELECT @@VERSION`)

Comment: What do you mean by "when I open the view in SQL Management Studio"? Are you using the visual view designer?

Comment: Yes I am using 2016 MS SQL Server.

Comment: And yes, I am using the visual Designer in SQL Server Management Studio. The problem is, that the Visual Designer complains when I open the SQL view in design mode in SSMS

Answer (score 0):

For whom it may concern:
Solved it by using an SQL function.

Maybe not the most elegant way but it seems to work.

`CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TODATETIMEOFFSETINTIMEZONE]
(
    @Date AS DateTime,
    @Timezone as NVARCHAR(100)
) 
RETURNS DateTimeoffset
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewDate As DateTimeoffset
    SELECT @NewDate = @Date AT TIME ZONE @Timezone
    RETURN @NewDate 
END
GO`

And in the SQL View

`SELECT 
    id, 
    TODATETIMEOFFSETINTIMEZONE(appointment_start, N'W. Europe Standard Time') AS appointment_start
FROM dbo.Appointments`